# Fancybox iframe says that my YouTube href is undefined

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, fancybox

Here is my HTML:

```
<a class="video iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psk2Pq03rv0&#38;fs=1">Arbitrary text</a>
```

Here is the Fancybox javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("a.video").fancybox({  
      'href'    : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),  
      'type'    : 'swf',  
      'swf'     : {  
        'wmode' : 'transparent',  
        'allowfullscreen': 'true'  
      }  
    });  
    return false;  
  });
</script>
```

Firebug Console says:

```
this.href is undefined  
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
```

As a result, clicking this link takes the user to YouTube and does not trigger Fancybox. 
Changing the problematic line to `'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch?v=", "i"), 'v/'),` which seems more correct to me, yields the same result.

Any advice?

EDIT: I adjusted my script to only include the parts relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Script tag should look like this**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.video").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
                'padding' : 0,
                'autoScale' : false,
                'title' : this.title,
                'overlayOpacity' : '.6',
                'overlayColor' : '#333',
                'transitionIn' : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'centerOnScroll' : false,
                'showCloseButton' : true,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                'type' : 'swf',
                'swf' : {
                'wmode': 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen': 'true'
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**url should look like this -** add **&fs=1** to the end of it

```
<a class="video iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psk2Pq03rv0&fs=1">Arbitrary text</a>
```

Comment: Well I sure wish I knew how to make my code pretty and structured like yours, but oh well. I apologize for not including the `$(document).ready` earlier - I thought that much would be assumed.

The `&fs=1` did nothing for me, but the `return false;`, which I neglected to replace after I moved this code over from another file, did help a little. Fancybox is triggered now, but the box is white and empty; the video never loads. Another stab at it?

I've updated my code appropriately.

Comment: $("a.video").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({

your code is still missing this part, and its important, its what makes the 'this' in the fancybox options work

Comment: Thanks wowo, but the link still goes to YouTube without triggering Fancybox. Here's what my code looks like at this moment, excluding all the unnecessary style properties:

`
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $("a.video").click(function() { $.fancybox({  
  'href'         : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),  
  'type'  : 'swf',  
  'swf'  : {  
   'wmode': 'transparent',  
   'allowfullscreen': 'true'  
  }  
 });  
 });  
 return false;  
});
`

Comment: move your return false up 1 line, it should be inside of the .click function like so.click(function(){init fancy box ... return false;}

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had changed the class name and didn't update it [again] when I copy/pasted your code. This works wonderfully. Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

this.href, in that context, is referring to document, not the anchor.

```
$("a.video").fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'autoScale' : false,
    'title' : this.title,
    'overlayOpacity' : '.6',
    'overlayColor' : '#333',
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'centerOnScroll' : false,
    'showCloseButton' : true,
    'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
    'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
    'type' : 'swf',
    'swf' : {
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'allowfullscreen': 'true'
    }
});
```

Is equally written as:

```
var options = {
    'padding' : 0,
    'autoScale' : false,
    'title' : this.title,
    'overlayOpacity' : '.6',
    'overlayColor' : '#333',
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'centerOnScroll' : false,
    'showCloseButton' : true,
    'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
    'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
    'type' : 'swf',
    'swf' : {
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'allowfullscreen': 'true'
    }
};
$("a.video").fancybox(options);
```

the anchor is not available in that context.

One option is to wrap the code in an each block

```
$("a.video").each(function(function(index, value)) {
   var obj = $(value);
   obj.fancybox({
        'padding' : 0,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'title' : this.title,
        'overlayOpacity' : '.6',
        'overlayColor' : '#333',
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'centerOnScroll' : false,
        'showCloseButton' : true,
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'href' : value.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type' : 'swf',
        'swf' : {
            'wmode': 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen': 'true'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This makes good sense, but there's a syntax error in your first line, can you spot it? "Missing formal parameter" is the error message - I'm not overly familiar with Javascript syntax, sad to say.

Comment: ah, index or value might be a reserved word, you can change them to something else.